# Cannot read property "Add Event Listener" of undefined

Tags: javascript

I managed to do a for loop so that I can select all my buttons in a div and attach an Event Listener to them. I get an error in a console although everything is working on the website:

> **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
> at index.js:5"**

Can I somehow fix this error?

Here is my code in js:

```
let div = document.querySelector(".set");
let nodeList = div.querySelectorAll("button");

for (let i = 0; i <= nodeList.length; i++){
  nodeList[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert("I got clicked!")
  });
}
```

Comment: `i <= nodeList.length` must be `i < nodeList.length`

Comment: In the console, what is `div`? what is `nodeList`? Maybe there's an iframe you don't know about that separates your browser console from the DOM.

Comment: I guess the approach is wrong. Rather than setting event listener on the each child you can set on parent one and use event bubbling to capture the data from the child button component,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are overrunning the list - change `<=` to `<` here: `i <= nodeList.length`
2. All newest browsers (Edge < 17 is an exception) can use forEach:
   `document.querySelectorAll(".set button").forEach(but => but.addEventListener(...))`
3. You are MUCH better off NOT looping but delegating

```js
document.querySelector(".set").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName === "BUTTON") { // assuming buttons have no other tags inside
    alert("I got clicked!");
  }
});
```

If your buttons contain tags, you can test one level up by adding
`|| tgt.parentNode.tagName==="BUTTON"` to the test

Comment: Unless there's a span or other element inside the button and the click comes from that… ;-)

Comment: @RobG Added a test for parentNode

Comment: It worked both ways and the second one is the better. Must remember that in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @Vukasin Do also pay attention to what RobG said  - I added a fix for that

Answer (score 0):

You are running your loop one too many times. It should be `i < nodeList.length`.

If `nodeList.length` is 3, you will 3 have elements in the array: 0, 1 and 2. So `i` should start at 0 and end at length - 1.

Comment: Unfortunately, Stackoverflow does not update without page refresh. So I cannot see that answers have been added since I have started writing my answer. This is common on new questions when everyone tries to answer at the same time. Also nobody bothered to explain to the Op, why they are overflowing the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way of looping over NodeList, your querySelectorAll returns NodeList not Array,

```js
for (const button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("clicked :)");
  });
}
```

Comment: No it is not different at all. You can loop over a nodelist using normal for loops, while loops and anything else using length. You can also use forEach in newest browsers

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan for letting me know, still learning I will update the answer

Answer (score -1):

Loop has an extra iteration when you use <= nodeList.length. It should iterate until i < nodeList.length.

```
let div = document.querySelector(".set");
let nodeList = div.querySelectorAll("button");

for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++){
  nodeList[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert("I got clicked!")
  });
}
```

Comment: @RobG added the explanation.